# Thingsboard shared attributes pulled from device

Tags: json, attributes, thingsboard

I am trying to get all shared attributes (45) from server to the device (ESP32). I created a full dashboard to update/modify all of the attributes. But I am facing 2 issues :

1. Identify the shared attribute that device is receiving.
2. What if my device in not online at the time attribute is updated? I did not find a way to pull all of the attributes.

So far I receive a json with the modified attribute. But I cannot identify which of the 45 attributes the device is receiving.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Hi Team. I managed to fix this apparent issue like this. 
Using ArduinoJson pair [link] (https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonobject/begin_end/) and I can manage now 60+ attributes. The hard part is to set them up in Dashboard and Device 1 by one.

Comment: I have the same issue, how do you solve it?
What needs to be published to get a list of ALL the shared attributes?

Answer (score 0):

On the second question, a device could ask for the attributes on any of the protocols. For example over [mqtt](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#request-attribute-values-from-the-server). The main idea is that you first request for the attributes to see the current values and then [subscribe](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#subscribe-to-attribute-updates-from-the-server) to see if there is any change on the attributes.

For the first question, I do not know the answer as you just get a list of key values.

Answer (score 0):

finally I managed to find the solution.
Yes, one is exactly as you mention. Subscribe to get the updates.

On the first question , not knowing which is the key, and to avoid to do a long case or else if... there is a solution in ArduinoJson called JsonPair, which actually does pretty much the same. Gets the key and updates the value in the JsonDocument ( coming from a file in this case ) previously parsed. here is a link which help me with this solution , I´ve spent many many hours trying to fix the issue.
https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonobject/begin_end/

Comment: as an extension of this thread for nodered users, there is an option to know which is the key that is coming...  i.e. msg.payload.hasOwnProperty ("key") . So you know which key are you receiving...  I think it is a good start . here the link where found this one. https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-to-test-for-undefined-in-function-node/19200/3